# JS: KeyShortcut to focus input - putting character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to focus main search bar input after pressing "s".

I have:

```
$("body").keypress(function(event) {
    if(do_focus == 1 && event.which == 115)
    {
        $('#search-global-input').focus();
    }
});
```

It's working fine, but after pressing "s" I am in input, but with that "s" character.
How to get that "s" character away? :)

I tryied to load the string, cut it via substr, but without results..

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use de preventDefault method of Jquery to stop de real event and do what you want without creating conflicts... (pretty nice on  elements to prevent redirections p.e)

```
$('#something').keypress( function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // your stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("body").keypress(function(event) {
    if(do_focus == 1 && event.which == 115)
    {
        $('#search-global-input').focus();
        event.preventDefault();  // this stops the default behavior
    }
});
```

Check out http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/